# How to find the coordinates of a square in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image and in that image i have a square and i want to find the center of the square i.e the coordinates of it and a point should point out the center of the square even when the square size is changed.

Comment: `for (int i = 320; i!=0; i++)`  I don't know what you think this is meant to do - but I can assure you it doesn't.  A debugger would've told you that very quickly.  I would suggest you find one and learn to use it as it's not possible to write modern programs without one.

Comment: I'm trying to move a pointer in my picture to the edge of the box....and it should give me coordinates of it

Comment: well, what's 320 + 1?  Is it closer; or further away from 0?

Comment: i think the logic in the code isnt appropriate so i removed it. I will try to do something else.

Comment: and i have edited my question of what i wanted to do, ur help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I once did something similar when I had to find center of palm/hand. I know that you can find contours, calculate appropriate HU moments and then find center of the contour form HU moments.

Comment: ok i will try the HU moments concept

Comment: but when i find the contour it is not accurate as my picture has a hash in the screen and i want the center of the square in the middle of the hash